# How does mounting of a recursive zfs snapshot behave in default mount directory .zfs/snapshot?

Tags: zfs, snapshot

I have a zfs pool called "data" on which I also put */var/lib/docker*. Due to docker (in my case; for the sake of the question docker is irrelevant) zfs list looks something like this:

```
data                                                                        1.33G   133G      660M  /data
data/1366b029121dbc907878e8a6fc5c481244b7aac11757fe63b94384fe64e48c6d       6.02M   133G      511M  legacy
data/272a5f859a53ec996868fb0e4953f2219aadbd96c0cd3b8b9be09ee550b7d0e5        236K   133G      511M  legacy
data/284641b6a43d2446be81ddf21fbeb70b781f6fb5f70025d88c44c19ed4728541        288K   133G  
...
```

Now, if I perform a snapshot I do it with the recursive option (*zfs snapshot -r data@snapshot-name*) to have a snapshot of all datasets (mine - /data - and the docker ones).

By default snapshots are mounted in *pool/.zfs/snapshot/snapshot-name*.

Can I safely use *pool/.zfs/snapshot/snapshot-name* as a source directory for (consistent, thus the snapshot) backups or am I missing some data, respectively does zfs mount my snapshots recursively? I did not find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Snapshots can be made recursively. But mounting a snapshot won't mount decedent snapshots. You can use [a script to mount snapshots recursively](https://github.com/Jip-Hop/zfs-backup-snapshots) to a specific directory, and then backup from there.

However, with regards to Docker, some data will be excluded using this method. Specifically the datasets with `legacy` mountpoint (and mountpoint set to `none`). ZFS won't automount them at boot and since the mountpoint doesn't contain a filesystem path (as opposed to `/data` in your example) it's not obvious where to mount their snapshots when performing a backup.

What I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60732362/1318145), is that Docker `lagacy` datasets contain the images for your containers. So you likely won't need to backup that data anyway.

Looking at your output from `zfs list` it seems you didn't make a dedicated dataset for Docker. That's why these Docker legacy datasets are stored under the parent dataset (the one you called `data`). I personally prefer to make a dedicated Docker dataset (could be under `data` too) to keep these legacy shares nested under the Docker dataset, like so:

```
zfs list -r data
NAME                                                                                    USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
data                                                                                   3.57G  2.63T      200K  /mnt/data
data/jip                                                                               2.27G  2.63T      208K  /mnt/data/jip
data/jip/docker                                                                         108M  2.63T     1000K  /mnt/data/jip/docker
data/jip/docker/4142fdca5ac3e7dbd12c0518e3377eb47a2c1a8599f564e07e08e5b25944146c        396K  2.63T      388K  legacy
data/jip/docker/43023791ce39ba890e8de50809cacda45a884b5990e4923fd6563eaed58e6b42        168K  2.63T      396K  legacy
data/jip/docker/98a9127ff2dd5fd2d0ea52f5e6343e85a8d2a80aa4cd2ffcf1c92e9b2d2b371f        101M  2.63T      102M  legacy
data/jip/docker/b68a666a8602cdbc3639b010558a0aa5f92f0b765a6efc15c4f7f30651ba2860       1.05M  2.63T      102M  legacy
data/jip/docker/b68a666a8602cdbc3639b010558a0aa5f92f0b765a6efc15c4f7f30651ba2860-init   216K  2.63T      102M  legacy
data/jip/home                                                                          2.16G  2.63T     36.9M  /mnt/data/jip/home
```